# how to count nested object inside array in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have data like this :

```
array: [
   0: [
     0: {fruits: "apple", price: "15000"},
     1: {fruits: "orange", price: "12000"},
   ],
   1: [
     0: {fruits: "grape", price: "13000"},
     1: {fruits: "chery", price: "14000"},
     2: {fruits: "longan", price: "12000"},
   ],
   2: [
     0: {fruits: "manggo", price: "16000"},
     1: {fruits: "dragon fruit", price: "17000"},
     2: {fruits: "avocado", price: "18000"},
     3: {fruits: "coconut", price: "19000"},
   ],
]
```

I wanna ask how to know the length of the second data, I already try using nested loop but the result is not same with my expectation my data come like this :

```
array: [
  0: {fruits: "apple", price: "15000"},
  1: {fruits: "orange", price: "12000"},
  2: {fruits: "grape", price: "13000"},
  3: {fruits: "chery", price: "14000"},
  4: {fruits: "longan", price: "12000"},
  5: {fruits: "manggo", price: "16000"},
  6: {fruits: "dragon fruit", price: "17000"},
  7: {fruits: "avocado", price: "18000"},
  8: {fruits: "coconut", price: "19000"},
]
```

and when I try to count all my data `the result : 9`, and how to count my total object inside my array? Expectation Result :

```
array 0 = 2, array 1 = 3, array 2 = 4
```

Comment: you want a count of the number of elements in each group?

Comment: yes sir, I wanna count of the number of my element inside the group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_map` (which in this case is more than sufficient enough):

```
array_map('count', $fruits)
```

If you prefer you can use the Collection methods to help get your count from each "group":

```
collect($fruits)->map(fn ($i) => count($i))->all()
```

Or shorter:

```
collect($fruits)->map('count')->all()
```

We create a Collection from the array and use the `map` method to iterate through each "group" (element of that array) and return the count of the "group". Then to get the array from the Collection, `all`.

[PHP.net Manual - Array Functions - `array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `map`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `all`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-all)

Comment: okey sir, thanks for giving the answer from this question, and you giving the documentation too. precise, concise, and clear answer

Comment: @LuckALip np, I added a straight PHP option as well ... good luck and have fun

Comment: okey sure noted for me, thanks for everything

Comment: I agree with @lagbox sir, array_map is sufficient as map method of collection uses array_map in background